# Problemas com IF no javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Sou inicianate em Asp.Net MVC, e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gerencia **Cursos** e na minha *tela* de **inscrição** estou tentando fazer uma validação `javascript` que caso o **aluno** já esteja inscrito em um curso e ele tente se inscrever novamente nesse mesmo curso, **deve aparecer** um *popup* `javascript` com  a mensagem **Você já está inscrito nesse Curso**. A outra validação é quando a **quantidade de vagas** chegar a ***zero***, o **status** do curso de deve mudar para **Encerrado** ao invés de ficar como **Curso Disponível**. Tentei fazer assim:

**View Inscrição**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>

<style>
    #Status {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .encerrado {
        background-color: green;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
        color: white;
    }

    .disponivel {
        background-color: orange;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
        color: white;
    }

</style>

<h2>Catálogo de Cursos</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Sigla
        </th>
        <th>
            Ementa
        </th>
        <th>
            Inicio
        </th>
        <th>
            Fim
        </th>
        <th>
            Turno
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantidade de Vagas
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sigla)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="~/Curso/Ementa?id=@item.Id">Ementa</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Inicio)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Fim)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Turno)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)" readonly class="Status" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qtd_Vagas)
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Inscricao", "Curso", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            if (item.Qtd_Vagas > 0)
                             {
                                 <a class="inscricao btn btn-success" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit(), Alerta()">Inscrição</a>
                                 <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" name="inscricaoId" />
                             }
                            else
                            {
                                 <input type="submit" value="Não há vagas" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"/>
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
<div class="form-group">

    <a href="@Url.Action("HomeAluno", "Home")"><input type="button" value="Voltar" class="btn btn-danger" /></a>

</div>
<br />


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Inscricao/",
                    data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") },
                    success: function() {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function Alerta() {
            var val = document.getElementsByClassName("inscricao").value;

            if (val != null) {
                alert("Cadastro realizado com Sucesso!");
            } else {
                alert("Você já está cadastrado nesse Curso!");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function Status() {
            var st = document.getElementsByClassName("inscricao").value;

            if (st != "Curso Disponível") {
                st = "encerrado";
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.Status').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "Curso Disponível") {
                    $(this).addClass("disponivel");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Encerrado") {
                    $(this).addClass("encerrado");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: O melhor era aproveitar o Ajax que já chamada o método de inscrição e devolver um JSON com o status. Dependendo da mensagem devolvida, você devolve uma mensagem diferente.

Comment: Cigano tem razão. Você faz uma chamada AJAX, o seu alerta deve estar no retorno desta chamada, não no evento click do link de inscrição. Na função status, quando você faz st="encerrado", você está modificando só a variável st, não o elemento "inscrição".

Comment: Mas não está claro onde/o que está dando errado no seu código. Tente explicar melhor o resultado que você está obtendo e porque não está bom.

Comment: Bom, no meu IF de **alerta** está sempre caindo nessa mensagem `alert("Você já está cadastrado nesse Curso!")`, ou seja no `else`, independente de está `null` ou não. @Cigano você poderia me dar algum exemplo do **JSON**, ainda não sei como usá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Novato. Concordo com o Cigano, o ideal é fazer uma requisição ajax ao servidor e verificar se o curso está disponível ou não.

Antes de entrar em detalhes sobre como fazer isso, vale explicar o motivo do problema que você está enfrentando.

O método `document.getElementsByClassName("inscricao")` retornará um array de elementos html, não um elemento específico. Sempre que utilizar este método, mesmo que só exita um elemento no DOM com esta classe, sempre informe o índice do array. Ex. `document.getElementsByClassName("inscricao")[0].value`

Como você não informou o índice do array, o valor da variável `val` sempre será `undefined`.

Uma forma de obter o value do elemento que recebeu o click seria assim:

```
$(".inscricao").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (!val)
    {
        alert("Cadastro realizado com Sucesso!");
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("Você já está cadastrado nesse Curso!");
    }

});
```

Para fazer a validação conforme a sugestão do Cigano você poderia fazer algo assim:

JavaScript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".inscricao").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Inscricao",
                data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") },
                success: function(retorno) {
                    alert(retorno);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

C# (Controller)

```
public class InscricaoController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index(int inscricaoId)
    {
        string mensagem = "";

        if (ValidarInscricao(inscricaoId))
        {
            MetodoParaFazerAInscricao();
            mensagem = "Cadastro realizado com Sucesso!"
        }
        else
        {
            mensagem = "Você já está cadastrado nesse Curso!";
        }

        return Json(mensagem);
    }

}
```